# ¿que funcion en java script me permite truncar un valor?

Tags: javascript

Necesito una función en **JS** que me permita truncar `4.5` a `4` por ejemplo
algo como `.truncate(x)`

Comment: Te recomendaría que hagas algun pequeño trabajo de investigación primero. Si ya lo has hecho, publica tu código y comenta que falla para poder ayudarte. Echale un vistado a [ask]

Comment: vnzlalibre bienvenido al sitio **es muy importante revises el documento [ask] ** que sugiere GDP, esto para tener buena aceptación en la comunidad y tengas buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 5):

Utiliza [`Math.trunc();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc)

```js
let miNumero = 4.5;
let truncado = Math.trunc(miNumero);
console.log("el numero: " +miNumero , "se trunco : " + truncado );
```

Comment: @Flowen ayudanos a que cuando los usuarios que pregunten, realicen preguntas de calidad al sitio, muchas de tus respuestas están contribuyendo a que usuarios puedan realizar preguntas que no son del contenido definido en [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `Math.floor(n)` para tuncar *n* a 4, en este caso

```
Math.floor(4.5); //Devuelve 4
```

Comment: `Math.floor` no trunca un valor sino devuelve el máximo entero menor a un numero dado

Comment: Si usas Math.floor(x); Siempre te devoverá el valor truncado

Comment: `Math.trunc` es el metodo correcto, mira la definición de [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/floor)

Comment: por cierto una prueba sencilla para demostrar que esta mal tu respuesta es la siguiente: `Math.floor(-12.5)` lo mismo ocurre para cualquier numero negativo  por la definición de `Math.floor` Devolver el mayor valor entero menor que el valor dado.

Comment: Vaaale. Perdona que empezara la discusión. No sabía que estaba equivocado. Yo siempre he usado .floor, por lo que pensaba que era la respuesta. Perdona las molestias que te he causado :(

Comment: Noy hay problema es un error común confundir estos conceptos, si quieres ver un poco mas [Funciones de parte Entera](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funciones_de_parte_entera), en este caso `Math.floor` te devuelve el piso.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, y por la comprensión ;-)

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta correcta a lo que  preguntaba @vnzlalibre es la siguiente: hay que usar la función `toFixed`, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
var numero = 5.56789; 
var conDecimal = numero.toFixed(2); 
// Igual a 5.57 
var entero = numero.toFixed(); 
// Igual a 5 (como un entero)
```

Comment: Hola Carmen, las respuestas no deben utilizarse para criticar o pedir aclaraciones. Lee [answer] para más información y consejos.

Comment: Como comentario, tanto `toFixed` como `trunc` devolverán el mismo valor, pero el tipo no será el mismo. `toFixed` lo devuelve como una cadena, mientras que `trunc` lo devuelve como un número. Dependiendo de lo que quiera hacer el usuario, uno de los métodos puede ser más conveniente que el otro.