# Cómo truncar un numero a 2 decimales en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy necesitando truncar la cantidad de decimales en un número en coma flotante  a un numero especifico y descartando el resto, de momento el único método que encontré es `toFixed` pero este redondea el valor no trunca:

```js
let num = 21.777777;
console.log(num.toFixed(1));
console.log(num.toFixed(2));
console.log(num.toFixed(3));
console.log(num.toFixed(4));
```

A alguien mas le paso, como lo resolvió, estaba pensando en convertir en un string y recortar la cadena, pero quiero saber si hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin tener que recurrir a eso.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿que funcion en java script me permite truncar un valor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106821/que-funcion-en-java-script-me-permite-truncar-un-valor)

Comment: @GDP No es duplicado, aquella pregunta es sobre truncar a un número entero, no con un número determinado de decimales

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta si es duplicado de [¿que funcion en java script me permite truncar un valor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106821/que-funcion-en-java-script-me-permite-truncar-un-valor) pero me parece que esta esta mejor, y deberiamos cambiar el order del duplicado, a pasar esta como principal

Comment: @jasilva se pide truncar con N decimales, no truncar al valor entero, mas si hay alguna forma de hacerlo que no sea convirtiéndolo en string y no es un problema arbitrario ya que hacer calculo para ciertos numero introduce algún tipo de error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDICIÓN**

Como se ha comentado, el código de la respuesta original tiene un fallo al hacer operaciones con coma flotante, y es que se pierden decimales.
Podemos solventarlo viendo si el número de decimales que el número tiene es menor o igual que el número de posiciones que hay que a truncar.

```js
function trunc (x, posiciones = 0) {
  var s = x.toString()
  var l = s.length
  var decimalLength = s.indexOf('.') + 1

  if (l - decimalLength <= posiciones){
    return x
  }
  // Parte decimal del número
  var isNeg  = x < 0
  var decimal =  x % 1
  var entera  = isNeg ? Math.ceil(x) : Math.floor(x)
  // Parte decimal como número entero
  // Ejemplo: parte decimal = 0.77
  // decimalFormated = 0.77 * (10^posiciones)
  // si posiciones es 2 ==> 0.77 * 100
  // si posiciones es 3 ==> 0.77 * 1000
  var decimalFormated = Math.floor(
    Math.abs(decimal) * Math.pow(10, posiciones)
  )
  // Sustraemos del número original la parte decimal
  // y le sumamos la parte decimal que hemos formateado
  var finalNum = entera + 
    ((decimalFormated / Math.pow(10, posiciones))*(isNeg ? -1 : 1))
  
  return finalNum
}

console.log(trunc(17.97, 2))
console.log(trunc(-17.977777777, 2))
```

O siguiendo esta idea simplificarlo de esta forma:

```js
function trunc (x, posiciones = 0) {
  var s = x.toString()
  var l = s.length
  var decimalLength = s.indexOf('.') + 1
  var numStr = s.substr(0, decimalLength + posiciones)
  return Number(numStr)
}

console.log(trunc(17.97, 2))
```

También hice unas pruebas que puedes ver [aquí](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/1976/0/trunc-benchmark).

Es del sitio en Inglés, pero quizás te interese echar un vistazo en las respuestas de [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912788/truncate-not-round-off-decimal-numbers-in-javascript) pregunta. [Ésta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41652921/3866134) es muy interesante.

**RESPUESTA ORIGINAL**

Con un poco de matemáticas:

```js
function trunc (x, posiciones = 0) {
  // Parte decimal del número
  var isNeg  = x < 0
  var decimal =  x % 1
  var entera  = isNeg ? Math.ceil(x) : Math.floor(x)
  // Parte decimal como número entero
  // Ejemplo: parte decimal = 0.77
  // decimalFormated = 0.77 * (10^posiciones)
  // si posiciones es 2 ==> 0.77 * 100
  // si posiciones es 3 ==> 0.77 * 1000
  var decimalFormated = Math.floor(
    Math.abs(decimal) * Math.pow(10, posiciones)
  )
  // Sustraemos del número original la parte decimal
  // y le sumamos la parte decimal que hemos formateado
  var finalNum = entera + 
    ((decimalFormated / Math.pow(10, posiciones))*(isNeg ? -1 : 1))
  
  return finalNum
}

console.log(trunc(17.977777777, 2))
console.log(trunc(-17.977777777, 2))
```

Comment: Perfecto, una solución sin tener que recurrir a conversión a otro tipo de datos como string, ya que necesitara usar el valor mas adelante y si convertía a string tendría que reconvertir a float el resultado para poder usarlo.

Comment: @RicardoD.Quiroga Prueba con `4.56` como entrada: es la razón por la que mi solución no usa números y por lo que comento los errores de redondeo

Comment: Tienes razon ese es un problema de representación que al multiplicar `4.56 * 100` da `455.99999999999994`

Comment: Edité la respuesta. Con una pequeña comprobación, el resto del código sigue siendo válido.

Answer (score 5):

No hay una función predefinida para hacerlo y no es trivial, porque hacer operaciones matemáticas con números en coma flotante siempre está abierto a posibles errores de redondeo, así que lo mejor es ir a lo seguro: transformar el número a una cadena de caracteres y luego quedarse con los decimales deseados:

```js
function dosDecimales(n) {
  let t=n.toString();
  let regex=/(\d*.\d{0,2})/;
  return t.match(regex)[0];
}

console.log(dosDecimales(3232.3456))
```

Explicación: la expresión regular se queda con números hasta que encuentra un punto. Luego se queda con los dos siguientes números que se encuentre (o menos, si no hay).

Nótese que la función devuelve un texto, no un número. Se puede transformar de nuevo a número usando la función `Number(texto)`

Comment: Esta forma sirve, el inconveniente es que hacer conversiones a string y usar expresiones regulares es un poco lento ademas si quiero utilizar el valor para alguna operación tengo que volver a convertirlo en float.

Comment: La idea es hacer todos los cálculos con el float y hacer el trunc sólo para mostrar el valor al usuario. No quites decimales durante los cálculos o empezarás a acumular errores

Answer (score 4):

Esta función es breve, clara, concisa y cubre (espero) todas las situaciones (3 diferentes). Para casos especificos se puede simplificar con solo eliminar lo que no se va a utilizar.

El calculo se realiza en los tres casos con pequeños cambios de la misma sentencia. Casos:

1. devolver numero (el concepto de ceros no significativos aquí no tiene sentido matemáticamente hablando).
2. devolver cadena de texto NO incluyendo ceros no significativos.
3. devolver cadena de texto incluyendo ceros no significativos.

En busca de la máxima simplicidad y elegancia prefiero esta nueva versión:

- 0. Calcular el valor:

  x = Number(x);
  decimalDigits = Number(decimalDigits);

a.    x = x * (10 ** decimalDigits); // desplazamos a la derecha el punto decimal tantas posiciones como indica decimalDigits;

b.    x = x - (x % 1); Calculamos la parte decimal del nuevo numero (x % 1) y se la restamos.

c.    x = x / (10 ** decimalDigits); desplazamos el punto decimal a la posición inicial.

(esta es la versión anterior que dejo por si alguien la prefiere:

```
x = parseInt(x * (10 ** decimalDigits))
                   / (10 ** decimalDigits);
```

Aquí parseInt era el que se encargaba de eliminar la parte decimal)

- 1. Devolver como número

return x;

- 2. devolver cadena de texto NO incluyendo ceros no significativos.

return x.toString();

d. toString() nos da la representación como texto del mismo número.

- 3. Devolver cadena de texto INCLUYENDO ceros no significativos.
     Lo mismo que en 2. pero cambiando el último paso de
     .toString()
     a:
     .toFixed(decimalDigits)

     return x.toFixed(decimalDigits)

d. toFixed(decimaDigits) devuelve una cadena de texto incluyendo si es necesario los ceros no significativos para que tenga exactamente el numero de caracteres decimales que indica decimaDigits.

toFixed(decimalDigits), si sobrasen decimales también los eliminaría -redondeando en vez de truncando- pero en este caso por los pasos anteriores sabemos que no sobra ninguno: Ya los hemos truncado en el paso b. (ver preparación. Apartado * 0.), a lo sumo faltan ceros no significativos.

```js
function trunc (x, decimalDigits = 0, returnText = true, longFixed = true) {
      /*
      decimalDigits = [0..15]
      returnText = true ->return is a string
                 false -> return is a number
      longFixed = true -> include non-significant zeros in the return string. 
            false -> NOT include non-significant zeros in the return string.
            *If returned is a number, the non-significant zero does not make mathematical sense. 
      
      decimalDigits = [0..15]
      returnText = true -> devuelve una cadena de texto
                   false -> devuelve un número
      longFixed = true -> si la salida es una cadena de texto incluye
                          los ceros no significativos necesarios para
                          completar la cantidad decimalDigits
                  false -> no se incluyen ceros no significativos
                  *Si lo que se retorna es un número es indiferente el
                        valor de este parámetro por no tener sentido matemático.
      */

      x = Number(x);
      decimalDigits = Number(decimalDigits);

      x = x * (10 ** decimalDigits);
      x = x - x % 1;
      x = x / (10 ** decimalDigits);

      if(returnText)
            if(longFixed)
                  return x.toFixed(decimalDigits);
            else
                  return x.toString();
      else
            return x;
   }

    console.log('trunc(x = 0.4444, decimalDigits = 2, ouputText= true, longFixed = false) = ' + 
          trunc(0.4444, 2,  true, false) + '\n');
          
    console.log('trunc(x = -0.4444, decimalDigits = 2, ouputText= true, longFixed = true) = ' + 
          trunc(-0.4444, 2,  true, true) + '\n');
          
    console.log('trunc(x = 0, decimalDigits = 2, ouputText= true, longFixed = false) = ' + 
          trunc(0, 2,  true, false) + '\n');
          
    console.log('trunc(x = -0, decimalDigits = 2, ouputText= true, longFixed = true) = ' + 
          trunc(-0, 2,  true, true) + '\n');
          
          console.log('trunc(x = 1.4444, decimalDigits = 3, ouputText= false, longFixed = true) = ' + 
          trunc(1.4444, 3,  false, true) + '\n');
          
    console.log('trunc(x = 1.6666, decimalDigits = 3, ouputText= false, longFixed = false) = ' + 
          trunc(-1.6666, 3,  false, false) + '\n');

          console.log('trunc(x = 1.4444, decimalDigits = 8, ouputText= false, longFixed = true) = ' + 
          trunc(1.4444, 8,  false, true) + '\n');
          
    console.log('trunc(x = 1.6666, decimalDigits = 8, ouputText= false, longFixed = false) = ' + 
          trunc(-1.6666, 8,  false, false) + '\n');

     console.log('trunc(x = 1.4444, decimalDigits = 8, ouputText= true, longFixed = true) = ' + 
          trunc(1.4444, 8,  true, true) + '\n');
          
    console.log('trunc(x = 1.6666, decimalDigits = 8, ouputText= true, longFixed = false) = ' + 
          trunc(-1.6666, 8,  true, false) + '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

También podrías utilizar la función toPesicion()
Lo que hace esta función es definir la cantidad de números que quieres que se muestren,incluyendo los decimales, además de es,también aproxima los números a una cantidad más próxima.
Ejemplo:

```js
let num = 21.777777;
console.log(num.toPrecision(1));
console.log(num.toPrecision(2));
console.log(num.toPrecision(3));
console.log(num.toPrecision(4));
console.log(num.toPrecision(5));
```

Comment: El problema es que esa función es como `toFixed`, redondea el valor. La pregunta expresamente pide no redondear, sino truncar

Answer (score 1):

tengo un ejemplo que te puede servir , te muestra el resultado sin redondear simplemente muestra el resultado y los dos primeros decimales:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
       <script src="../public/js/jquery_min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>





        <form name="form1" method="post"  action=""> 
            <p> 
                Primer sumando: <input  id="precio_venta" name="precio_venta"   type="text" size="8" maxlength="100">  
            </p> 
            <p> 

              <div class="col-sm-3">
                                             <div class="form-group label-floating">
                                                    <label class="control-label">IVA</label>
                                                    <select id="porcentaje" name="porcentaje" class="form-control selectpicker">
                                                        <option disabled="" selected="">Seleccione ...</option>
                                                        <option value="1.05">5%</option>
                                                        <option value="1.19">19%</option>



                                                    </select>


                                                </div>
                                                </div>



            </p> 




            Original number: <input name="original" type="text"  />  



            <p>
                Resultado es: <input id="resultado" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10"> 

                    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" style="color:#FFFFFF;" onclick="porcentaje_iva();"><i class="fa fa-dollar fa-1x fa-lg" style="color:#FFFFFF;"></i> Calcular IVA</button>

            </p> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
            function porcentaje_iva()
            {  



                if(porcentaje.value == "1.19" || porcentaje.value == "1.05" ){

                var n1 = Math.floor(precio_venta.value * 100) / 100;

               var n2 = Math.floor(porcentaje.value * 100) / 100;

               $(function() {

           document.form1.precio_venta.value=(n1 / n2);

             var n = Math.floor(precio_venta.value * 100) / 100;


             var x= precio_venta.value=(n1 / n2);

             document.form1.precio_venta.value= n.toFixed(2);

        });

                }


}


        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo encontré una manera con javascript.

```
function formato(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    e = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var input = this.shadowRoot.getElementById(e.id) ;

    //aquí elimino todo lo que no sea números o comas (,)
    var num = input.value.replace(/\,/g,'');
    if(!isNaN(num)){
    //convierto a string
    num = num.toString();
    //separo los caracteres del string
    num = num.split('');
    //invierto el orden del string
    num = num.reverse();
    //junto todos los caracteres de la cadena
    num = num.join('');
    //busco los dos primeros caracteres y le coloco una coma en la siguiente posición
    num = num.replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{2})/,'$1,');
    //invierto del contenido de la cadena y reemplazo todo lo que no sea números o comas
    num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\,]/,'');
    //asigno la cadena formateada al input
    input.value = num;
    }
}
```

el input lo formatea  así: 00000,00

La documenté por si alguien necesita hacer alguna adaptación le sea mas fácil ubicarse donde hacerlo.